# How to write Bengali text in a tree/chart?

Tags: xetex, tikz-trees, polyglossia

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,multi]{standalone}

\usepackage{forest,array}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
% Replace this with whatever font you're using
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
                align={@{}C{25mm}@{}},
            },
            draw,
            font=\sffamily\bfseries,
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            l sep=10mm,
            tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
            edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
            ultra thick,
            inner color=gray!5,
            outer color=gray!20,
            rounded corners=2pt,
            drop shadow,
        }
        [\textbengali{বাংলা ট্রি}
        [B1]
        [B2
        [C1]
        [C2]
        ]
        [B3]
        [B4]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

This gives:

[image]

I want :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is font-related, as the error messages in the log indicate.

The document has no sans font defined, so the default sans font is used, and it has no Bengali, so that the forest's command, `font=\sffamily\bfseries`, has the expected result.

Akaash font is a sans font; it has Latin and Bengali letters; it has no bold, but a bold can be faked. These three things are useful.

So, if keeping Akaash font is desired, there are two solution paths available: (A) make Akaash the document's sans font and keep using `font=\sffamily\bfseries`:

`\setsansfont{Akaash}[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0]`

or, (B) use Akaash in the forest via the polyglossia method and change the forest font command to `font=\bengalifont\bfseries`:

`\newfontfamily\bengalifont[AutoFakeBold=4.0,Script=Bengali]{Akaash}`

In both cases, the fake bold option will be needed.

---

(A) Set Akaash as the document's sans font and define a fake bold for it.

[image: document sans]

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
\setsansfont{Akaash}[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,Renderer=HarfBuzz]%HarfBuzz for lualatex.
% Replace this with whatever font you're using
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Akaash}%HarfBuzz for lualatex.

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
                align={@{}C{25mm}@{}},
            },
            draw,
            font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{blue},
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            l sep=10mm,
            tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
            edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
            ultra thick,
            inner color=gray!5,
            outer color=gray!20,
            rounded corners=2pt,
            drop shadow,
        }
        [\textbengali{বাংলা ট্রি}
        [B1]
        [B2
        [C1]
        [C2]
        ]
        [B3]
        [B4]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```

(B) Leave the document sans font undefined, but use bolded Akaash font for the trees.

[image: forest sans]

MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest,array}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}p{#1}}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}
%\setsansfont{Akaash}[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,Renderer=HarfBuzz]%HarfBuzz for lualatex.
% Replace this with whatever font you're using
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[AutoFakeBold=4.0,Script=Bengali,Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Akaash}%HarfBuzz for lualatex.

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
        for tree={
            if level=0{align=center}{% allow multi-line text and set alignment
                align={@{}C{25mm}@{}},
            },
            draw,
            font=\bengalifont\bfseries\color{red},
            edge path={
                \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-5mm) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
            },
            parent anchor=south,
            child anchor=north,
            l sep=10mm,
            tier/.wrap pgfmath arg={tier #1}{level()},
            edge={ultra thick, rounded corners=2pt},
            ultra thick,
            inner color=gray!5,
            outer color=gray!20,
            rounded corners=2pt,
            drop shadow,
        }
        [\textbengali{বাংলা ট্রি}
        [B1]
        [B2
        [C1]
        [C2]
        ]
        [B3]
        [B4]
        ]
    \end{forest}
    
\end{document}
```